# Use jquery on if validation of simple Js

Tags: jquery

I have this lines of code

```
 if (document.getElementById("nosok").value==""
    ||document.getElementById("hnosok").value=="0")
  { 
    $( function() {jAlert("blabla!", "blabla")});
   return false;
  }
```

The trouble on IE is that the modal window doesn't close after clicking the OK button and further more it spreads on the full width of the page.

I just wanted to replace the alert() line and hence losing the ugly pop up box with jquery's more elegant way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would look into using http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: alert is native javascript. You should modify your code so your doing the actual check when the DOM is ready.

Comment: I'm just trying to change the alert box. I want it though to trigger only when the if statement finishes. Appart from that if i just used simple alert() everything would work fine. i want the graphical result of th jquery modal though.